# Web scraping twitter

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

I want to do web scraping on twitter page to download tweets on a specific search word. I am not able to fetch recursively all the tweets, rather I can fetch 20 tweets. Please help to fetch all the tweets recursively. Below is the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

company_name = 'ABC'
url = 'https://twitter.com/search?q=%23%27%20%20%20' + company_name + '&src=typd&lang=en'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers);#print(req)

data = req.text;# print(data)
# soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml");# print(soup)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser");# print(soup)


tweets = [p.text for p in soup.findAll('p', class_='tweet-text')]
# print(tweets)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Tweet'] = tweets
print(df.head())
print(df.shape)
```

Comment: Why are you not using Tweepy ?

Comment: I have used both the Rest(search API) as well as streaming API but due to its limitation on number of tweets to be fetched, just exploring this option

Comment: Yes..that is the problem there...But it can be handled if you schedule your Tweepy code every 1 hour or so and keeps on appending data to your df

Comment: Yes... But trying this option so that all the tweets can be fetched in one go. Please let me know if you can resolve the above issue

Comment: I guess because the tweets are loaded in dynamically. You can use Selenium for that.